# Setting an XSL variable to a node-set using conditions

Tags: xslt

This question is very similar to [XSL store node-set in variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5302535/xsl-store-node-set-in-variable). The major difference is that if XPath does not find a node which matches the filter, I would like to return the first unfiltered result.

The code I have here works, but I feel like it is a hack and not good XSL style. In this case, each chapter node is identified by a string id. The variable `showChapter` is the string identifying a chapter. If no chapter is found with this id attribute, I want to return the first chapter.

Relevant code:

```
<xsl:param name="showChapter" />

<!-- if $showChapter does not match any chapter id attribute, 
     set validShowChapter to id of first chapter. 
-->

<xsl:variable name="validShowChapter">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="/book/chapter[@id=string($showChapter)][position()=1]">
            <xsl:value-of select="$showChapter" />
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="/book/chapter[position()=1]/@id" />
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>

<!-- I want $chapter to be a valid node-set so I can use it in 
     XPath select statements in my templates 
-->
<xsl:variable 
    name="chapter"
    select="/book/chapter[@id=string($validShowChapter)][position()=1]"
>
```

Is this approach as poor of a hack as I think it is, and if so could you point me to a better solution? I am using XSLT 1.0 processed by PHP5's XSLTProcessor, but XSLT 2.0 solutions are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work. A lot of the usage of `position()` and `string()` in your example were unneeded, btw:

```
<xsl:param name="showChapter" />

<xsl:variable name="foundChapter" select="/book/chapter[@id = $showChapter]" />
<!-- Will select either the first chapter in $foundChapter, or
     the first chapter available if $foundChapter is empty -->
<xsl:variable name="chapter" 
              select="($foundChapter | /book/chapter[not($foundChapter)])[1]" />
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I knew what I'm writing is too ghastly to be the most elegant solution.